# Clustering using K-means algorithm for documents

Tags: distance, documents, k-means

How i calculate the distance between two documents? In the k-means for numbers you have to caculate the distance between two points. I know that i can use the cosinus function.
I want to perform clustering to rss documents. I have done stemming and removed the stop words  from the documents. I  have counted the frequency of word in each document. And now i want to implement the k-mean algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your difficulty is in creating the feature vector?  Create a feature vector for each document by

1. Collecting together all words to form a giant vector
2. Setting the elements of that vector to be the count of terms.

For example, if you have

```
Document 1 = the quick brown fox jumped over the brown dog
Document 2 = the brown cows eat hippo meat
```

Then the total set of words is [the,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over,the,dog,cows,eat,hippo,meat] and the document vectors are

```
Document 1 = [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
Document 2 = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

And now you just have two giant feature vectors that you can use to represent the document and you can use k-means clustering.  As others have said, Euclidean distance can be used to calculate the distance between documents.

Comment: How do you run these document vectors through k-means? Do you have to iteratively compute the distance between each document and each other document?

Answer (score 1):

There various distance functions. One is the [**Euclidean Distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the euclidean distance formula for an n-dimensional system.

```
sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1 - z2)^2 ... )
```